# SSRS Tablix filter out NULLs

Tags: visual-studio-2012, filter, null, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

I'm working on trying to filter out records in my Matrix and I have a column group called Description which is grouping records by Open, Assigned, Completed and NULL values. I'm currently trying to filter out that column group so that it only shows Assigned and Completed...and filters out the Open and the NULL.

I know that I right click on Tablix Properties and go to Filters, and I choose Description <> Open and it works. But how do I filter out the NULL records in that same section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter on nulls by using a formula like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dude, you are awesome! Thank you for saving me again! It worked. Appreciate you.

Comment: Oh hey @smul86! Glad to have helped haha